# How to become a football referee?

Tags: football, officiating

I've recently been ruled out of football because of injury problems (though I am still fit and able to run, just need to avoid contact sports) but still want to get involved, which got me thinking - what does it take to qualify as a referee for competitive football?

Obviously I don't expect to be off refereeing in the champions league final at the end of the season, but it would great to get to referee in proper competition as soon as possible.

I am in sweden so rules should be specific to sweden/swedish leagues, though I could also do training in the uk. Any advice on speeding up the process would also be good.

Comment: You're talking professional football?  Not just like local leagues?

Comment: Long term yes, meantime local leagues will be fine (and good way to try it out and get experience). Looking for insight on how to go further with it

Comment: http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/get_involved/4660333.stm here's an article that gives you some information.

Comment: Don't want to sound whiny, but did you even [google](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bli%20domare%20i%20fotboll) that? Assuming you speak Swedish to a reasonable level, there's a considerable amount of information available out there, should be a decent start

Answer (score 3):

Have a read of http://svenskfotboll.se/ for starters, then send them an email. They should be able to advise of when their next introductory course will take place, and what's required to take part.

Good luck with it, officiating is an amazing way to stay involved in a sport, and can be a source of immense satisfaction and enjoyment.

Answer (score 2):

Contacting the Swedish FA, as suggested by TrueDub, seems the obvious step given that you are in Sweden.

For the UK, it would be a similar procedure, get in contact with either the FA (England) or the scottish FA (Scotland), who both seem keen on recruiting new referees.

[Link to FA (England) website on how to get started refereeing](http://www.thefa.com/my-football/referee/general-information)

[Link to Scottish FA website on how to get started refereeing](http://www.scottishfa.co.uk/scottish_football.cfm?page=2062)

(note the opportune advertising deal in scotland by the way!)

Answer (score 1):

Watch before as this may be managed not by the national FA but by a local league for bginners, as it is the case in France for example. You'll maybe need your club's support, for example for what is related to the refereeing jerseys and kits.

All leagues require a theorical test about Laws Of The Game and some require a physical test which may be the [Cooper test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_test) of the Werner-Helsen one. Keep training and running then !